# How to change image backarrow color depending on the layout background image color?

Tags: android

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)itemUserProfileBinding.ivItemUserProfile.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

       // Bitmap imageProfile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(),arrayList.get(position).getProfile());
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(20,20);

        int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
        int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
        int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

        int invertedRed = 255 - redValue;
        int invertedGreen = 255 - greenValue;
        int invertedBlue = 255 - blueValue;

        itemUserProfileBinding.ivUserProfileBackArrow.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, invertedRed, invertedGreen, invertedBlue));
```

In above code `itemUserProfileBinding.ivItemUserProfile` is my background imageView and `itemUserProfileBinding.ivUserProfileBackArrow` this is my custom toolbar back arrow imageView.

I have tried above but it is not working, can any one please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `but it is not working` what does it do? How exactly is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't properly understand your question but if you want to invert the complete bitmap then get each pixel in the image and then invert its RGB values.

If itemUserProfileBinding.ivUserProfileBackArrow is your imageview then I think you should first get the bitmap from the imageview and then invert the colours of that bitmap and then set the inverted bitmap to your imageview.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Palette class to generate color and change it accordingly

```
//Gradle dependency 
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:2x.x.x'
 }

// Java
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new PaletteAsyncListener() {
   public void onGenerated(Palette p) {
     // Use generated instance
     // this is an Async call, You will get following colors in respect to bitmap

    /*Vibrant
     Vibrant Dark
     Vibrant Light
     Muted
     Muted Dark
     Muted Light*/

     itemUserProfileBinding.ivUserProfileBackArrow.setColorFilter(p.getMuted(0x000000));

   }
});
```